# Simple javascript for a clock not working

Tags: javascript

Hi this is my first javascript and it is not working. The script is programmed to display a clock. The code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="clock.js" > </script>
</head>
<body onload=display_ct();>
<span id='ct' ></span>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript is :

```
function display_c(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
var strcount
var x = new Date()
document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
tt=display_c();
}
```

When execute I get a blank screen. What and where is the mistake ?

TIA :)

Comment: try to write your js code in the same HTML file in between `<script type="text/javascript">` tags.

Comment: Your code runs well. No errors.

Comment: There are few corrections, but let me know which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably be consistent with ending lines in semi-colon. Also, you should check that `clock.js` is loading; finally put the `onload` handler in quotes like

```js
function display_c() {
  var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
  mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh);
}

function display_ct() {
  var x = new Date();
  document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
  tt = display_c();
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="display_ct();">
  <span id='ct'></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please enclose your onload attribute value of body tag inside " " .

It should be

```html
<body  onload="display_ct();">
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setInterval()`, also this line won't work in some browsers:

```
setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
```

```js
var ct;

function display_c() {
  //timer block
  setInterval(function() {
    ct.innerHTML = new Date().toString();
  }, 1000); //execute every 1 second
}

function display_ct() {
  ct = document.getElementById('ct'); //initialize once.
  display_c();
}
```

```html
<!-- onload, enclosed in quotes -->

<body onload="display_ct()">
  <span id='ct'>Loading ...</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You made two errors when entering the `display_ct` function. You needed to wrap the `<body>`'s `onload` event with quotes, and remove the quotes and the parentheses on the `setTimeout`. See below.

```js
function display_c() {
  var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
  mytime = setTimeout(display_ct, refresh);
}

function display_ct() {
  var x = new Date();
  document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
  display_c();
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="clock.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="display_ct()">
  <span id='ct'></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your input, just adding on to what you explained how do I align the display to top center ? I tried the align tag but it does not work.

Comment: Learn more HTML. Search this site for your answer.